# Deny delete access for all users except a specified user in windows server 2008

Tags: permissions, network-shares

I want to set permissions for a folder and all its files in a way that all users are permitted from delete except user identity A. Is that possible?
I checked deny for everyone (for delete access type)  in advanced permission setting, but after that the user A either couldn't delete the files although I checked the allow for it. How can I exclude a specific user from an access rule.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably have to uncheck `Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent` when modifying permissions for a viewed-directory. That setting seems to be a rule that quickly setups permissions based on a criteria of who gets to see what and how (*correct me if i'm wrong*).

Answer (score 0):

`Deny` takes precedence over any other permission, thats why User A was not able to delete the files.

Give `Everyone` view access only and give the individual User A delete access.

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Directory of `\\server\users\` is the total amount of id's (*like so*):

- \\server\users\id1
- \\server\users\id2
- \\server\users\id3
- \\server\users\id4

So, then if I `deny` - `\\server\users` in general then that means in order to allow particular user(s) it'll have to be by adding every single id mentioned and only allow those particular id's and manually go through the rest and deny the remaining id's. **This is a lot of work** and I think it could be done in a better way, any ideas?